Filing under the attorney's customer number or client's customer number?
The USPTO has just emailed me my customer number.
My question, when the attorney files my provisional application, if they file under my customer number, would I be able to log in and view the progress of the application?
So the objective is to be able to view the progress of my application when it is filed by the attorney.
